# Wrap text into pdf while create pdf using dompdf from PHpExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, dompdf

we are using phpexcel and dompdf library to export html reports to pdf.
but having issue with table column when text length is long.

Text goes outside of pdf .
[image: i attached a screenshot of my pdf. can see contents are cuts.]

```
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
```

Can anybody help?

[image: snapshot][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjz83.png)

Comment: We are going to need a lot more code than that.

Comment: Can we wrap text individual column wise ?

Comment: Are you wrapping the text inside the PHPExcel cell?

Comment: yes, i want to wrap text inside table cell . but not working. Due to long text width of table cell goes high and pdf don't show table perfect. Some columns are truncate.

Comment: dompdf can wrap text in a cell, so the issue probably relates to how PHPExcel is styling the content. Would help to see the relevant HTML/CSS.

Comment: we have already set  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$starting_row_num.':'.$last_column_char.$row)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true); but still it not wrap text and counting width of column as per long text length